# Adview from Admob shows blank box if no Internet connection

Tags: android, admob, ads, adview

I just tried to include an Adview in my layout. Works just fine, except that it shows a blank space if there is no Internet connection. As I have read so far, I understand that the standard behaviour for an admob is to take space only if the Ad is shown. Otherwise, eg. no Internet connection, it should take no layout space. I'm listing the code where I think I might have made a mistake and that's why I encounter this odd behaviour...

```
<LinearLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:background="#FFFFFF"
       android:weightSum="1">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       android:id="@+id/toolbar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
       app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
      android:id="@+id/adView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      ads:adSize="BANNER"
      ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then, in app gradle:

```
dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.2.0'
 }
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And in module gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

I think I have done something wrong, so please help me with an advice. 
Thank you!

Comment: the box has any borders or its just empty area?

Comment: No borders, empty area...

Comment: I recommend check for internet connection and hiding if not available.

Comment: Yes, I know I could do that, but I want to find out why I'm getting this behaviour and if it only happens to me or it is a general issue..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Add this Code to your class file

```
AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);
            adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: let me know that your issue is fix or not by using my answer code ?

Comment: Thanks, I will try it... But what I realy wanted was to know WHY I get this behaviour.. Is it happening all the time (to leave this space) to everybody and there is no other solution just to ad a listener ?......

Comment: Once the ad view is gone, it won't show up again. `Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.`